# http header not passing correctly

Tags: performance, jmeter, http-headers

so i'm creating an API scrip in jmeter with only one request (GET). this request requires to pass some http headers, which I add it in the HTTP HEADER MANAGER. These are the headers:

Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}
Content-Type: application/json
X-County-Code: 19

I see in the request all these headers, but in the response data I see it fails giving a 400: Bad Request and it mentioned that the X-County-Code header is invalid.

Just for the record, the same script passes ok with all these header in Vugen, and if I remove the X-County-Code in Vugen I get the same error in the response data.

Any Ideas? thanks

Tried adding it at the top of the test plan and also within the transaction. but still no luck. Tried in the latest jmeter version as also in 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTTP Header Manager and the actual headers which are being sent using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener or 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), it might be the case it's a copy-paste issue and you're sending an extra unprintable character like whitespace.

With regards to the placement, HTTP Header Manager obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

If you're capable of running the request using Vugen you can just record it using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder or use one of the [LoadRunner to JMeter conversion options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/loadrunner-jmeter-conversion).

[image]